# Application with Multiple Modules: shared vs separate data types

Tags: web-app, information-architecture, data

This is my first post here, I apologize if this is confusing but I attempted to make it clear as possible.

The web application is one big application for multiple related teams. We have split up these teams functions into multiple modules with mostly unique data, but some of this data is shared throughout. I am struggling to determine when the data should exist outside in an admin panel or be manipulated within the modules. Here is a particular example I am looking at:

- We have two modules, one is for maintaining items (such as laptops) and one is for maintaining people.
- Both modules have locations, these locations are shared between modules. The data they share includes: Name and Address.
- In both modules, at different times you need to be able to create new locations or add existing locations, such as when filling out a form.
- In the people module, you can assign people to the location whether that is their work or hotel location.
- In the items module, you can request that specific resources come from specific locations.

So my questions here is:

- Since both modules share locations, do I create a place outside of those modules to manage ALL locations such as a location manager? Or you can only view all those locations from inside one of the modules?
- If I create a location manager, how should I handle adding a new location within a module? Do I need an option to add a new location whenever adding an existing one? Eg. within the module via a modal or popping a new window with the location manager.

Comment: welcome to ux.se! Can you provide some kind of scheme or user flow? Right now the question looks too broad

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

From a user's perspective, authorized users should be able to add locations where they need them. We have a modular application that includes locations for people, companies, offices, airports, etc. Users can search, open, select, or create new locations in the location popup window from any module either in the actual records they are adding the location to or in the admin data location menu. In my experience exposing the capability wherever it may be needed is always preferable to users.